# Criticize This And/But Advocate That

Tags: conjunctions

Both *and* and *but* are coordinating conjunctions and used to connect the following *criticize* and *advocate.*

> Experts *criticize* the exclusive use of device X and/but *advocate* the use of its alternatives such as device Y.

Which one is more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that example, there is no opposition between the two statements, so "and" should be used.

This is an example that would call for "but":

> Some experts criticize the exclusive use of device X, **but** some others think it is acceptable.